# Solve failing and not clear why

Tags: equation-solving

I define the function:

```
 w[q_, n_, a_] := q/(4 Pi n r^2) (1 - Exp[-2 r/a] (2 (r/a)^2 + 2 (r/a) + 1))
```

I then want to solve:

```
 q = 1.6*10^(-19);
 n = 8.85*10^(-12);
 a = 0.529*10^(-10);
 Solve[w[q, n, a] == 1000, r]
```

This does not work and I do not understand why. I think there is a solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Reals` option with `Solve` since you did not use exact numbers. You'll get an answer (also with `Solve::ratnz`) along with it

```
Solve[w[q, n, a] == 1000, r, Reals]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you. You show NSolve, but Solve works. Why does your display show the result in that long form as opposed to mine showing it in scientific notation?

Comment: @Amzoti sorry, copied the wrong command. It is Solve, not NSolve. I tried NSolve earlier also to see what it does. But ended up using Solve with Reals.